# Data from observable not displaying

Tags: angular, observable, reactive-programming

In my project, I use Observables in service to hold data taken from DB. So I subscribe to it in my main component.

**In search.service, the data retrieving function**

```
  getData(){
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
      this.db.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) subscriber.error(err);
        subscriber.next(docs);
      });
    })
  }
```

**In main component**

```
  getData(){
    this.searchService.getData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.datum = data;
        console.log(this.datum)},
      err => console.log("E", err)
    );
    console.log(this.datum);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
  }
```

Here are the results I get in the console

[image: Results in the console]

From this I understand that while in the context of `.subscribe()` method, property `datum` is assigned the contents of database, but outside of it, it is still undefined. 
I don't get why it happens, or how to display the contents of DB. All the tutorials I've found suggest that after I subscribe to observable and assing in the subscription method the property of my component to result passed in observable, everything should stay this way and I should be able to display it easily in the component.

Been bashing my head against this for a month or so and had no luck with articles on observables. Seems like I get the principles but, no matter what, can't put them to use.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

(I don't want to resort to using promises, because observables seem a little more general in terms of their applicability and it seems that learning them is a very potent skill to have)

EDIT

The html template for the component.

```html
<!--The whole content below can be removed with the new code.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
    Data: {{datum}}
  </h1>
```

EDIT 2

View

[image: View]

Comment: db.find() is **asynchronous**. That's why it doesn't return the values it finds, but instead takes a callback as argument, to notify you when the data is available. So you can't expect to have the data immediately after subscribing to your observable. You'll have them (as the logs show) only when the observer is called. Why it's not displaying is another matter. Post the template of your component.

Comment: I get this. But why then the results of db.find() stored in the property datum? In the demplate I have the interpolation  syntax like this {{(datum | async)}}, but it doesn't display anything

Comment: I've marked this as duplicate. If you think it's not, please comment and I'll cancel it

Comment: It's very similar, but the difference is that I already get that to have my result logged I have to call the log function inside the subscribe() method, but don't know how to display the results after assigning as it seems that property storing the results remains undefined

Comment: How do you try to display it? If it's like `{{(datum | async)}}`, you are using it wrong because `async` is a pipe for observables. Remove the pipe and simply use it like `{{ datum }}`

Comment: This is how I try to display it. I've tried just {{datum}} and <span *ngFor="let data of (datum | async)">{{data}}</span>. Neither worked

Comment: datum is not defined in the component, the result of GetData(), variable "data" in subscribe() method is an array

Comment: You have a comment with `ngFor` for your html but now you are saying you don't in your edit. This seems like an xy problem

Comment: @echonax Don't know if I understand what you are saying, In my comment I said that I tried the `ngFor` implementation as well as with and without `async` pipe, and none of them did work

Answer (score 2):

[Follow the numbers in comments; they represent order of execution]

```
getData(){
    this.searchService.getData()
        .subscribe( //1. subscrube just registers what will happen when data comes and immediately goes to next call
            this.successHandle.bind(this),//3. this will run only when data comes which might be a year from subscription
            err => console.log("E", err)
        );
    console.log(this.datum); //2. runs immediately after subscribe
  }

successHandle(data){
    this.datum = data;
    console.log(this.datum) //4. logs data when it comes
}
```

your line 2. logs 'undefined' as there is no data yet at that point. you are just subscribed, but data will come in future

Comment: Thank you, it's a little clearer now, but do I need a separate function in the component to do the assigning? The goal is to be able to use the data I get from DB to populate the template. Now the interpolation in the template does nothing

Comment: This answer is wrong because `this` inside the `successHandle` method won't refer to the component hence `this.datum` will be undefined.

Comment: well, there you have several options, from `async` pipe to manual resolving. for start, i would suggest you check this in docs: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#async-services-and-promises

Comment: @echonax, what will `this`refer to if not the component?

Comment: It will refer to the `successHandle` methods instance. You should read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: oh, ok ok, of course...but that's a whole another point...point here was to illustrate the flow blocks.

Comment: @deezg yes the flow is correct of course but if the OP tries to execute this it will not work. I'll edit it for you (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: no problem, of course, you are completely right. thanks for edit!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing Asynchronous call, and `console.log(this.datum);` outside your subscribe in Component will run while your data is being fetched from DB, and when it is done, then `console.log(this.datum)` in your subscribe will run. That is the whole story of Observables and callBacks..